# Why would Hinata leave Naruto in 'The Last'?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto: The Last*, why did Hinata leave Naruto for Toneri? Just when Naruto was beginning to develop feelings for her, too. I don't get it.

Comment: have you seen the entire movie? remember that Naruto: The Last is set before Chapter 700 of the Manga, **before** Hinata and Naruto have their children Boruto and Himawari. Hinata leaving Naruto, at least to my understanding (having not seen the movie myself, going off the wiki), was to help Hanabe as Toneri agreed to spare her and the eventual return of her Byakugan if Hinata accepted his marriage proposal.

Comment: Hmm, I dont know, But it is probably to save her sister and learn what Toneri plans to do in the future,

Answer (score 2):

Hinata chose to left Naruto and went with Toneri because..

1. Hinata and the others doesn't know where Toneri's castle in which Hanabi is in.
2. She did that to save her sister.
3. And to learn what other future plans Toneri intends to do.